# IntelliJ - Unable to start Tomcat 8. Starts fine via comand line

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, configuration, intellij-idea

I'm a complete noob to IntelliJ and Tomcat 8. I managed to configured Tomcat 7 in IntelliJ in the same manner (as configuring TC8) and it works normally. Also, TC8 works when I start it up using command-line.

Here's what IntelliJ tells me when I try to run TC8:

> "Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop,
>   reason: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub:
>   javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is
>   java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection
>   establishment; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException:
>   Connection reset]"

Logs:

> C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.8\bin\catalina.bat run Using CATALINA_BASE:
>   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0" Using
>   CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.8" Using CATALINA_TMPDIR:
>   "C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.8\temp" Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre8" Using CLASSPATH:
>   "C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.8\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.8\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
>   Jun 06, 2014 1:22:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>   WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [C:\Program
>   Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\conf\server.xml] Jun 06,
>   2014 1:22:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load WARNING:
>   Unable to load server configuration from [C:\Program Files\Apache
>   Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\conf\server.xml] Jun 06, 2014 1:22:08
>   AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start SEVERE: Cannot start
>   server. Server instance is not configured. Disconnected from server

Comment: Is your tomcat server is running ? and from where you have tried to connect or start tomcat server ? Because as per my knowledge it's working fine for me.

Comment: That's the problem. I can't get it run. I hit the green play looking icon in the top right corner of intelliJ when the Tomcat 8 configuration is selected. It begins to start, but fails and I get the messages above.

Comment: Stop Tomcat Service if running then check your `edit configuration` once then create it's instance for your web application then try to run it.

Comment: You mean create a new configuration?

Comment: Wait I am posting answer.

Comment: It worked! Thanks man. Don't know why, but simply creating a new configuration with the same exact settings worked.

Comment: Have you perform following steps ? or else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps :

Configure new Tomcat Server :

[image]

After configure click on OK.

Then on that one <kbd>+</kbd> symbol is there click on it i.e. in Green color, it shows :

[image]

then last step is to configure it for application :

[image]

from deployment tab add exploded file of application then configure that in which browser you want to open application then click OK, if you want to change more settings then you can.

Then try click on Green Button that will run your application.

Comment: btw, what's the difference between exploded and non-exploded war deployment?

Comment: when it's exploded then and if you have select on `Update` action then it will redeploy application and when you have war or non exploded then you have to restart server which changes to take effect, let me check and get back to you if I am wrong.